# How to Compare Data gridview and Database field for Update Process

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm doing winforms.. In that I'm comparing the datagridview column value and db value..

If the DataGridView column exist in db I want to do update process if not exist, I want to do Insert process.

I tried this code

string resultJewelId = null; string QueryJewelId = null;

```
private void AddStockTable()
{
    try
    {
        Sqlcon = objDB.DBConnection();


        QueryJewelId= "Select JewelId from tblStock";

        Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(QueryJewelId, Sqlcon);


        dr = Sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    resultJewelId = dr.GetString(0);

                    if (resultJewelId == dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Update process");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Insert Process");
                    }
                }
            } 

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
}
```

While condition working fine.. But I don't know how to move next row value in for loop..

Kindly support me.

Comment: SQL has a WHERE statement that allows you to find the value without looping yourself in code.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is write a stored procedure which checks for data existence and updates database accordingly

```
Create procedure AddorUpdateStock
@JewelId it,
--remaining columns
if not exists(select JewelId from tblstock  where JewelId = @JewelId)
begin
--insert
end
else
begin
--update
end
```

You loop through all rows in datagridview  and call this procedure